# The mbstring is missing - NGINX PHPMYADMIN PHP 7.0.23 CENTOS 7

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, nginx, centos

como posso resolver esse erro, pois estou usando o php7, e nao consigo baixar essa extensão.
php 7.0.23
Nginx
Centos 7

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Creio que no CentOS bastaria digitar:

> **Atenção:** use isto somente se você instalou o php via repositório oficial, caso contrário ignore este passo

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

---

No entanto se estiver instalada ou você não estiver usando o PHP via **repositório oficial**, mas sim adicionando via `rpm` ou usando Xampp ou outro tipo de coisa então geralmente já vem instalado então basta habilitar no `php.ini` removendo o `;`, abra o php.ini e procure uma linha como esta:

```
;extension=mbstring.so
```

E então removendo o ponto-e-virgula (`;`) deve ficar assim:

```
extension=mbstring.so
```

Após isto reinicie o Apache ou Xampp ou Wamp (ou seja lá qual for o tipo de instalação que fez), se for Apache instalado via repositório digite isto no terminal:

```
apachectl restart
```

Ou:

```
/sbin/service httpd restart
```

Se for Xampp creio que será algo como (geralmente instalado em `/opt/lampp`):

```
/opt/lampp/lampp stop
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Ou talvez restart (eu não sei afirmar se lampp tem restart):

```
/opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Answer (score -1):

Muito obrigado pela resposta.
Ao instalar yum install php-mbstring, apresenta erro de de instalação, comflito com meu php7.0.23
Eu estou usando php-fpm, no centos.
e no meu php.ini não tem essas opções.